# Adding updated attachments after an start and wait for approval in power automate

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I want to add updated attachment in my workflow but suddenly I don't know what should I put in "send an email V2".

I tried to put 'link to item' but suddenly it only shows the list in SharePoint. I want to add the attachment only, once you have receive the email,you can click the attachment and automatically open or shows the content of attachment.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a flow as steps in the following article. I have tested it and successfully.

https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/power-automate-send-an-email-with-an-attachment-from-sharepoint/

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you?

If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.